# Get only days ago the node was posted - Drupal 7

Tags: php, datetime, drupal, drupal-7

How can I get only days ago the node was posted?

E.g. If node post date is yesterday only print "1" or node post date is 1 month and 1 week ago only print "37"

I am trying to solve this by using following snippet but failed

```
<?php echo 'Posted: ',format_interval(time()-$node->created); ?>
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format_interval()` function formats a time interval with the requested granularity.

For example if current Unix time is 1427868018 and node created time is 1366045256:

- `format_interval((time() - $node->created) , 1))` returns "1 year",
- `format_interval((time() - $node->created) , 2))` returns "1 year 11 months",
- `format_interval((time() - $node->created) , 3))` returns "1 year 11 months 2 weeks",
- `format_interval((time() - $node->created) , 4))` returns "1 year 11 months 2 weeks 6 days".

If you want to display only days, you can use following code:

```
$intervalSeconds = time() - $node->created;
$intervalDays = floor($intervalSeconds / 86400);

print $intervalDays;

if ($intervalDays == 1) {
    print ' day';
} else {
    print ' days';
}
```

It will return "715 days".

Comment: With the caveat that Daylight Savings Time can throw it off a bit, but if the exact value isn't needed, your solution is good enough.